# Optimal source code in R to calculate the least squares regression line? Then calculate sum of errors squared.

Tags: r

The points given are (1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (3,1), (4,1), (4,2), (5,2), (6,2).

So, from what I've gathered so far- I start with the following:

```
x = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6)

y = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)

model = lm(formula = y ~ x, x=T, y=T)

model <- lm(y~x) 

summary(model)
```

From here on is where I'm having difficulty understanding the intuition of what I need to accomplish next.  I get that this gives me the data but past that I'm stuck.  Any advice?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: A useful function for using model results:  `?predict`. Also, the `lm` object you've created, named model, contains a bunch of interesting info. Try `str(model)` to see what is there.

Comment: `print(model)` prints some info and `coef(model)` gives the regression coefficients.  `deviance(model)` gives the sum of squares.  Also try `summary(model)` and `plot(model)`.

Comment: So is there a specific function that's output is my least squared regression line?  I know how to plot it, use the summary func, or coef- each of which are giving me interesting information- but as far as answering the question, I'm still not seeing how these are accomplishing that.

Comment: The coefficients define the line.  `fitted(model)` gives the fitted values on the line that correspond to the x values.